# DocuSign event notification for template creation

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

My scenario is when a template is created/deleted at DocuSign portal then is there any way DocuSign notify my application that a new template has been added or deleted. So that I can sync my DocuSign portal and application database in the context of templates.
Just like DocuSign notify about Envelope status event when the envelope is sent/Signed/completed etc. to a custom webhook, just like that needed for a templated creation or deletion, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We don't provide that capability currently. You can always call our API endpoint `/{{apiVersion}}/accounts/{{accountId}}/templates` to get a list of templates and cache it locally for comparison later.